# How to use Prime Faces 3.1? How to update from Prime Faces 2.2 to Prime Faces 3.1

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Prime Faces 2.2, but now i want to use Prime Faces 3. I downloaded the Prime faces3.1.1 jar and included it into my project. I am using Netbeans 6.9. Then i create a simple project and include the Prime Faces 3.1.1 jar and then tried the code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <p:inputTextArea id="inputarea" rows="5" cols="30"/> 

    </h:body>
</html>
```

But it is giving me error undeclared component:( Do i need to do something more in order to use Prime Faces 3 in my project. Also i want to ask is Prime Faces 3 is compatible with Prime Faces 2.2? One of my project is using Prime Faces 2.2. I also want to use Prime Faces 3 in that too. How can i update from Prime faces 2.2 to Prime Faces 3. Just including the Prime Faces 3.1.1 jar is enough?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You forgot to add the `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" into your`html`tag`
 and if you already taglibs you can add the `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core`  and `xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets`as well (you might use it later on)

2) NO , you can't use primefaces 2 and 3 in the same project and you can't just replace the jars , follow this [Migration Guide to 3.0](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide)
for example , you can't use the listeners of the components you used to in the 2.2 project , instead , use the `p:ajax` with the proper events

also you should read in the User Guide about how to use the components you used to use in primefaces 2.2 project [User Guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_1.pdf)

Comment: HHmm thanks. But the guide is saying that in 2.2 we use `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"` and in 3 we use `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`. Also saying about events. And that's it. I mostly used **p:dataTable, p:panel, p:focus, p:tooltip** and ajax event in my project. So what i understood is that included the jar and change the namespace and it starts working... Is it? What you suggest?

Comment: Also please tell  me What is **Prime Faces RC**. It just contain bug fixes? Thanks

Comment: RC = Release Candidate , read ... http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Release+Candidate

Comment: You mean to say i can't use both PrimeFaces 2 and 3 features on same page. OK what if i have two pages. On one page i use PrimeFaces 2.2 namespace, and on second page i use PrimeFaces 3 name space.Both have different name spaces. I am using **p:ajax** events, I didn't use any events without **p:ajax**. That's why i said that changing the namespace is enough in my case.

Comment: You should not use both PrimeFaces 2 and 3 in the same page and in the same project... even if you somehow succeed in using them both it will get back at you eventually... You better migrate to PrimeFaces 3 (only) , regarding the p:ajax thing... take a look at the User Guide pdf... you will notice that instead of XYZListener inside the components primefaces expects now <p:someComponent><p:ajax event "XYZ"></p:someComponent>

Comment: hhmmmm ok, I just want to make sure that using both on same project is safe or not. Actually what i was thinking that include both the libraries. And now i am creating new pages in my project, so on new pages i use Prime Faces 3. Leave the previous pages as it is with Prime faces 2.2. But as you are saying that this is not right, so i see that after removing the Prime Faces 2.2 jar what errors come and then try to remove them. Is this approach is ok?

Comment: Yes , replace the old jar with the new one , and read the Migration Guide... then start googling to resolve the errors...